# Android app cannot open socket on phone

Tags: android, sockets, permissions

I'm developing an app that utilizes network connection. I've already added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>` to AndroidManifest.xml and the application ran fine in the Eclipse's emulator. Once I transferred it to my phone, that part broke down and I can no longer open a client-side socket.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the stack trace you are getting

Comment: please add the logcat output

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to either of those things. I've not been able to debug the app running on the phone with Eclipse since Eclipse doesn't not list the device. I just installed the apk and ran the app.

Comment: @Kyltmer That should be your main concern then.  Without a log, there is not much we can help you with.  At least try and catch the error and report it with a `Toast`.

Comment: I added a few toasts and discovered an exception was being thrown from a part of the program I was not expecting. It was tracked down and fixed. App is working now. I feel kinda noob-face for not realizing that...